# Building the dataset for Random Forest training procedure

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree, random-forest

I should use the *bagging* (abbreviation for *bootstrap aggregating*) technique in order to train a random forest classifier. I read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) the description of this learning technique, but I have not figured out how I initially organize the dataset.

Currently I first load all the positive examples and immediately after the negative ones. Moreover, positive examples are less than half of the negative ones, so *by sampling from the dataset uniformly*, the probability of obtaining a negative example is greater than that of obtaining a positive example.

How should I build the initial dataset?
Should I shuffle the initial dataset containing positive and negative examples?

Answer (score 2):

Bagging depends on using [bootstrap samples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29) to train the different predictors, and aggregating their results. See the above link for the full details, but in short - you need to sample from your data with repetitions (i.e. if you have N elements numbered 1 through N, pick K random integers between 1 and N, and pick those N elements to be a training set), usually creating samples of the same size as the original dataset each (i.e. K=N).

One more thing you should probably bear in mind - random forests are more than just bootstrap aggregations over the original data - there is also a random selection of a subset of the features to use in each individual tree.